# what is the difference between consistent connection and long polling?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, long-polling

I am new to SignalR and I try to understand the difference between consistent connection and long polling,Is there different use in methods ? is one better than the other? are there any diffrenet functions need to polling and other functions to use consistent connection?, I googled but didn't find a simple answer to this question, can someone help? need an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a framework that allows us to build real-time web applications. Ideally, we would use web sockets for this. However, web sockets is a new protocol and requires support from both the browser and the server. Thus, web sockets are not generally available and SignalR tries to provide an abstract connection similar to web sockets but built upon existing technologies and techniques. This abstraction is called a Persistent Connection.

**Persistent connection** is the term used to describe SignalR's abstract connections.

**Long polling** is one of several techniques used to implement SignalR's persistent connections (the others are **Forever Frame**, **Server-Sent Events** and **Web Sockets**).